# Optimized way for finding the number which satisfies specific conditions

Tags: python, python-2.7, math

I saw this question somewhere. 
There is a 8 digit number. First digit from left to right tells how many zeroes in the number. Second digit tells you how many 1s in the number, third digit tells u how many 2 in the number and so on till 8th digit which tells u how many 7 in the number. Find the number.
So I wrote a piece of code in python to find out the digit. Apart from the conditions mentioned above, I have few additional checks like 'sum of digits should be 8' and 'no 8 or 9 should be present in the number'. I've pasted the code below. This is just brute force since  I take every number and check for conditions. I was curious to know if there is any better way of solving the problem

```
def returnStat(number, digit, count):
    number = str(number)    
    digit = str(digit)
    print "Analysing for ",digit," to see if it appears ",count, " times in ",number,"."        
    actCnt = number.count(digit)
    count = str(count)
    actCnt = str(actCnt)
    if (actCnt == count):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

def validateNum(number):
    numList = str(number)
    if '8' in numList:
        print "Skipping ",number, " since it has 8 in it"
        return (-1)
    elif '9' in numList:
        print "Skipping ",number, " since it has 9 in it"
        return (-1)
    elif (sum(int(digit) for digit in numList) != 8):
        print "Skipping ",number, " since its sum is not equal to 8"
        return (-1)
    index = 0
    flag = 0
    for num in numList:
        if (returnStat(number,index,num)) :
            index = index+1
            continue
        else:
            flag = 1
            break 
if (flag == 1):
    return (-1)
else:
    return number

for num in range(0,80000000):
number = '{number:0{width}d}'.format(width=8,number=num)

desiredNum = "-1"
desiredNum = validateNum(number)
if (desiredNum == -1):
    print number," does not satisfy all "
    continue
else:
    print "The number that satisfies all contition is ",number
    break
```

Comment: Complete, working code that you're interested in improving belongs on Code Review, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'd be happy to learn different solution as well. I'm not just looking for answers to improve my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you iterate over all 8 digit numbers with no 8s or 9s in them, there's not many possibilities (actually, 8^8 = 1<<24 ~= 17 million).

Here's a naive program that tries them all:

```
import itertools

for digs in itertools.product(range(8), repeat=8):
    counts = [0] * 8
    for d in digs:
        counts[d] += 1
    if counts == list(digs):
        print digs
```

It completes (with exactly one solution) in 15 seconds on my machine.

To make it faster, you can only consider 8-digit numbers whose digits add up to 8. Here's the same code as before, but now it uses `sum_k` to produce the possibilities. (`sum_k(n, k)` generates all `n`-digit tuples where all the digits are less than 8 which sum to `k`).

```
def sum_k(n, k):
    if k < 0 or n * 7 < k: return
    if n == 1:
        yield k,
        return
    for d in xrange(8):
        for s in sum_k(n-1, k-d):
            yield (d,) + s

for digs in sum_k(8, 8):
    counts = [0] * 8
    for d in digs:
        counts[d] += 1
    if counts == list(digs):
        print digs
```

This code completes in 0.022 seconds on my machine.

Adapting the code to solve the general case produces these solutions:

```
1210
2020
21200
3211000
42101000
521001000
6210001000
72100001000
821000001000
9210000001000
```

Comment: Even I check for the "sum" condition on my code, but takes more than a minute to find. Maybe because the condition is within the loop. But this is cool.

Answer (score 3):

You can go further than to simply say that digits of 8 or 9 are impossible.

Can the last digit ever be greater than 0? The answer is no. If the last digit was 1, this means there is one 7 somewhere else. However, if there is a 7, it means that the same number has occurred 7 times. This is clearly impossible. Thus the last digit has to be 0.

So we have xxxxxxx0.

What about the second to last digit?

If xxxxxx10, then there has to be at least one 6, which means the same number occurred 6 times. We can try 60000010, but this is incorrect, because there is a 1, which should be reflected in the second digit. The second to last digit can't be higher than 1 because 2 means there are 2 sixes, which in turn means one number occurred six times while another number also occurred 6 times, which is impossible.

So we have xxxxxx00.

If xxxxx100, then there has to be at least one 5, which means the same number occurred 5 times. Let us start with 51000100. Almost, but there are now 2 1s. So it should be 52000100. But wait, there are now one 1. and one 2. So we try 52100100. But now we only have 4 0s. We can't have xxxxx200 because this means there are 2 5s, which is impossible as explained above.

So we have xxxxx000.

If xxxx1000, we can try 40001000, nope, 41001000, nope, 42101000.

Ah there it is. 42101000.